# メーラーを立ち上げずにメール送信

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

こんにちは。
iPhoneアプリでメールを送信する方法を探しているのですが見つからず、解らなかったので質問させていただきます。

サーバーに*POST*せず、メーラーを起動させずに（メール編集画面を表示させずに決まった宛先、タイトル、本文は引数で挿入）メールを直接送信させたいのですが、そのような機能は可能なんでしょうか？
また、可能であればご教授の程宜しくお願い致します。

追記：2015/05/26 14:40
ringringさん、fkmさん。ありがとうございます。教えていただいたサイトを参考に作業を進めてみたいと思います。

Comment: 「メールアプリ」を作るイメージでしょうか？

Comment: アプリで取り込んだデータを送信というものです。
今のところ、テキストデータのみを考えています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そういうことでしたらsmtpクライアントが必要になるかと思います。
以下で言及されているライブラリはいかがでしょうか？

http://ksksue.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/01/23/022127

SwiftからObjective-Cのライブラリの使い方がわからなければ
こういうのが参考になるかもしれません
http://qiita.com/kazutoyo/items/dcc3cc99409852708553